# How to loop through an array of checkboxes and a MySQL database without overlap?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, overlap

```
for($j = 0; $j < $length; $j++){
    while($answersRow = mysql_fetch_row($fetch)){
        if($answersRow[0] == $curr_answer_id[$j]){ 

            echo "<input type='checkbox' value='$answersRow[0]' checked>$answersRow[1]</input> ";           
        } else {

            echo "<input type='checkbox' value='$answersRow[0]'>$answersRow[1]</input> ";           
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming `$fetch` is my result, here's my dilemma. The `for` loop represents the `array of checkboxes`. The first loop around, everything works fine. However, any more than that, we no longer cycle through the `while loop` because of the internal mysql pointer. I know I can move the pointer around using `mysql_data_seek()`, but don't have an idea on how to do so usefully. If I move it back to 0, then it just outputs everything for as many things that were checked.

I basically want to traverse through for each question through the database but without any overlap. It is a bit hard to explain so I apologize if I am not explaining this simple problem properly; I'll try and clarify if need be.

Comment: have you tried resetting the pointer after the  `while () {}` loop (but inside the `for () {}` loop?

Comment: your question is almost incomprensibile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the results of your first while in an array:

```
//> FIRST LOOP
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rows[] = $row; //> Saving in the $rows array
    //> All your code from your first loop
  }

//> SECOND LOOP    
  foreach($rows as $v) {
   //> All your code you need for your second loop without any additional query
  }
```

Also sorry If I misunderstood your question but It is not so clear what you are asking for

### Addendum

After reading better your question if I understood correctly you want to achive everything **within only one loop**. In this case you can save the html you need in the first while like this:

```
$firstLoop = '';
$secondLoop = '';
while() {
   $firstLoop .= '<option> [...]';    
   $secondLoop .= '<div> [...]';
}
```

At this point with one loop you have built the html you need and they are in `$firstLoop` and `$secondLoop`. This is of course faster then any other solutions